# Propagation of light in a time-varying refractive medium

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

Spatial gradients in the refractive index of a medium have an impact on the wavelength, frequency, and direction of waves propagating through them.

What about media whose refractive index changes (spatially uniformly) with time? Is it correct to say that there will be no changes to wavelength or direction of propagating waves?

What equations should be used to model wave propagation in a medium with time-varying refractive index? As a bonus, how would we model propagation if the index is changing *non-uniformly* in both time and space?

Comment: This video from Don Lincoln at Fermilab is fun - [Are time crystals real?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hV2Vxfxu47k)